Handling Communication Disruptions Between Services in a Distributed System: Strategies for Online Stores and Warehouses
There are two services running on separate machines: an online store and a warehouse. The online store acts as the downstream customer in relation to the warehouse, which serves as the upstream supplier designed to cater to various types of stores.
When a customer pays for a product, the store sends a request to the warehouse to deduct the purchased quantity of items from the inventory. The request successfully reaches the warehouse, and the items are deducted. However, the response back to the store is not received due to a connection interruption. Attempts to restore the connection fail, resulting in the store and the customer being unaware that the items have been deducted and dispatched.
This situation resembles the Two Generals' Problem in computer science.
What algorithms are commonly employed in real-world scenarios to address such challenges?

If communication is never restored, there is no way to address this challenge: it's likely that some inventory will be delivered without the store collecting payment (assuming that the store's process is collect payment when sure that inventory has been deducted and shipped)

Under an assumption that communication is eventually restored, the general principle that holds (using this terminology) is to resend requests until such time as an acknowledgement is received: this generally implies that the recipient needs a means to identify requests which are resends of requests it has already handled, in which case it acknowledges without doing anything (this generally requires some means of uniquely identifying requests and maintaining enough state in the recipient to know that a request has been handled).

one possible solution which comes two my mind is that we can localize the failure in the online store:

online store sends the request to warehouse for deducting and processing product, the body of the request contains a callback url.
the warehouse sends a callback request to the online store. and when it gets "OK" response from the store it starts deducting and processing products.
this will let put all responsibility to online store side. the money will be changed from the customer but it can be refunded later when they realize that the product wasn't processed on the warehouse.


There must be some best practices and literature about such challenges which will allow me not to reinvent the wheel
